# Insert a row into Room using Rxjava on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

This article says that I can use `Completable` as return type for `@Insert`
But as I do that, the error occured:

```
error: local variable pointToInsert is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

This error happens with AndoridX since Rxjava return types support included only since 2.1 version : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63317956#comment25

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertPoint(pointToInsert: ControlPoint): Completable
```

So, how to make this thing work?

Answer (score 0):

As this feature is completely unavailable unless you use version 2.1+, you can actually solve this problem using lower version by making some kind of adapter for you DAO:

```
@Dao
interface Original {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertPoint(pointToInsert: ControlPoint)

}

class AdHocCompletableAdapter(private val dao: Original) {

    fun insertPoint(pointToInsert: ControlPoint) = 
        Completable.create {
            dao.insertPoint(pointToInsert)
            it.onComplete()
        }
}
```

Or create some more flexible solution (using, for instance, function composition).